# Xdebug not working in eclipse:no progress after launching upto 57%

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I had implemented php Xdebug in eclipse PDT. I am using Ubuntu system. I could use Xdebug successfully in a sample project. 
But when I tried it in a codeigniter project and started debugging from a view page a url like /myproject/application.views/view_name.php was loading in external browser(firefox) but was showing an error- *Forbidden You don't have permission to access*.I am testing in localhost.

I tried setting the variables 
`$config['uri_protocol']   = 'PATH_INFO';` and
`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`
Even I changed the port to 8999/9001 in xdebug.ini and eclipse.On trying to debug the eclipse shows a status "launching 57 %" and continues without progressing ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the db files as described in this post: [Five tips for speeding up Eclipse PDT and nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/blogs/nwire/2010/09/five-tips-speeding-eclipse-pdt-and-nwire).